# Mostrar u ocultar elementos dependiendo de dos radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, html5

He logrado hacer mostrar un `div` según la respuesta de **un radio button**, pero ¿cómo puedo hacer para mostrar el mismo `div` pero con la combinación de **dos radio button**?

Comparto mi código:

```js
function mostrar(dato) {
  if (dato == "1") {
    document.getElementById("nombre").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("apellidos").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("edad").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (dato == "2") {
    document.getElementById("nombre").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("apellidos").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("edad").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (dato == "3") {
    document.getElementById("nombre").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("apellidos").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("edad").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group" id="opciones">
        <label for="">Opciones:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="opc" value="1" onchange="mostrar(this.value);">Solo nombre
        <input type="radio" name="opc" value="2" onchange="mostrar(this.value);">Solo apellidos
        <input type="radio" name="opc" value="3" onchange="mostrar(this.value);">Solo edad
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="nombre" style="display:none;">
        <label for="">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="apellidos" style="display:none;">
        <label for="">Apellidos:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="edad" style="display:none;">
        <label for="">Edad:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edad">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Este seria el otro div con el qué me gustaría hacer la combinación-->
<div class="form-group" id="masOpciones">
  <label for="">Opciones2:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="opc" value="">Municipio
  <input type="radio" name="opc" value="">Ciudad
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Brian, no entiendo bien lo de la combinación de dos radio button, en principio no se puede seleccionar dos radio buttons a la vez que tengan un mismo name. podes explicar bien esta parte?

Comment: Hola Leonardo, según la sintaxis de html no se pueden seleccionar dos radios button si estos se encuentran en el mismo div, por lo cual los tengo separados, lo que quiero hacer y ando algo perdido es que la respuesta del primer radio más la del segundo me llame un div. ¿Si me explique bien?

Comment: Si leen los comentarios del código en el segundo div dice que quiere combinarlo con el segundo set de radios..  @BrianVelez la duda que tengo es, tienes que hacerlo con js puro? o tienes permitido usar jquery?

Comment: @Killbunny, Si es con Js me ayudaria bastante, pero con Jquery también me gustaria aprender a realizarlo, ¿con cual de las dos opciones me andaría mejor?

Comment: Por qué pensaste en vanilla? nadie lo mencionó.

Todavía no se entiende lo que quieres hacer, tienes un set de opciones `radio`lo que muestra un div, ahora tienes otro set de opciones y quieres mostrar un segundo div? no entiendo la parte que dices "quiero combinarlo con este (set de opciones)"

Comment: Necesitas dar un nombre distinto a los radiobuttoms que quieras agrupar, da igual que estén en el mismo div o en uno diferente

Comment: Confundí un poco los términos, edite mi comentario por lo mismo.

Comment: Me explico mejor: tengo dos set de opciones lo que quiero lograr es que al marcar la respuesta de un set + la respuesta de otro, pueda llamar un div

Comment: bien ahora tenemos dos set de opciones que deben mostrar un div, el primer set tiene 3 opciones y el segundo tiene 2 opciones eso me hacen 6 combinaciones, eso quiere decir que debo tener 6 divs? o se hará de otra forma, creo que tienes que explicar un poco mas la lógica que estas siguiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tenés que cambiar los "=" por ":". Ejemplo:

```
document.getElementById("nombre").style.display: none;
```

Yo lo hice así:

```
var y = document.getElementById("codigo");
y.style=  "display:none";
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es cambiar el atributo `name` de tu segundo set de radios. Seguido de eso tienes que verificar si ambos cuentan con respuesta, si ambas respuestas tienen valor, entonces puedes mostrar lo que necesites.

Con JS puro:

```js
var set1 = document.getElementsByName("opc");
var set2 = document.getElementsByName("opc2");

var val1=null;
var val2=null;

function mostrar(){
 for (var i = 0;  i < set1.length; i++)
  {
   if (set1[i].checked)
   {
    val1=set1[i].value;
   }
 }
  for (var i = 0;  i < set2.length; i++)
  {
   if (set2[i].checked)
   {
    val2=set2[i].value;
   }
 }
  
  if(val1!=null && val2!=null){
  //Muestra aqui lo que necesites mostar
    document.getElementById("nombre").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("apellidos").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("edad").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <form action="" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="form-group" id="opciones" >
                    <label for="">Opciones:</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="opc" value="1" onchange="mostrar();">Solo nombre
                    <input type="radio" name="opc" value="2"  onchange="mostrar();">Solo apellidos 
                    <input type="radio" name="opc" value="3"  onchange="mostrar()">Solo edad
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="nombre" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"  >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="apellidos" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="">Apellidos:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos"  >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="edad" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="">Edad:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edad"  >
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Este seria el otro div con el qué me gustaría hacer la combinación-->
<div class="form-group" id="masOpciones">
    <label for="">Opciones2:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="opc2" value="M" onchange="mostrar()">Municipio
    <input type="radio" name="opc2" value="C" onchange="mostrar()">Ciudad
</div>
```

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto puede servirte para lo que intentas hacer: 
(Usando Jquery)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //Capturas el cambio de algun input radio
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
  
    //Ocultas todo 
    $("#nombre").hide();
    $("#apellido").hide();
    $("#edad").hide();
  
    //obtenes el valor de los dos sets de Radios
    var opc = $("input[name='opc']:checked").val();
    var opc2 = $("input[name='opc2']:checked").val();
    
    //tomas la decisión que queres en base a los dos valores
    //en este caso si selecciona "nombre" y "ciudad" mostras el input text para el Nombre
    if(opc == 1 && opc2 == 2)
      $("#nombre").show()
      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="opciones" >
    <label for="">Opciones:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="opc" value="1">nombre
    <input type="radio" name="opc" value="2">apellidos 
    <input type="radio" name="opc" value="3">edad
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="masOpciones">
    <label for="">Opciones2:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="opc2" value="1">Municipio
    <input type="radio" name="opc2" value="2">Ciudad
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="nombre" style="display:none;">
    <label for="">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"  >
</div>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Leonardo muchas gracias,  tu ejemplo me ayudo mucho!